# FPS camera in c++ maybe using glm:lookat

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have a rather simple setup, a model at 0,0,0, with:

```
projection = glm::perspective(fov, aspectRatio, near, far);
model = glm::mat4(1.0);
```

I want a flexible camera, which is, from what I read the best described as FPS camera.

Now I am having:

```
glm::mat4 CameraMatrix = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(cameraPosition.X,cameraPosition.Y,cameraPosition.Z), // camera, in world space
        glm::vec3(cameraTarget.X,cameraTarget.Y,cameraTarget.Z),   // direction vector eye + Dir
        glm::vec3(upVector.X,upVector.Y,upVector.Z) 
        );
```

very much as described here: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-6-keyboard-and-mouse/

This is working out fine except one thing, mouse up and down does as intended, but left-right rotation the mouse makes the model rotating around cameraposition and not camera rotating around the model? Did I make something wrong?

My impression is that this requires at least some additional rotation and maybe translation to make it work correctly. If so, I am wondering why this seems to be mentioned nowhere. There are plenty of tutorials using lookat also if referring to "FPS camera" when I google for it. This confuses me a bit.

Now the examples around glm::lookat are rather poor and I read some stuff for gluLookAt in which I heard some voices that at least gluLookAt is no solution for such a task, does the same apply to glm::lookat? And if so, what's the right way to go? I am really not bound to glm:lookat in any way, it's just when I stumbled across it, I was like "HEY! Just what I was looking for" and it seems to be a clean and easy solution. 
Maybe someone can shed some light on this and point me into the right direction or tutorial.

Comment: AFAIK glm::lookat is the exact same thing as gluLookAt, just with glm types rather than with the OpenGL matrix stack.

Comment: Perhaps this tutorial is what you're looking for: http://www.learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Camera. Describes the logic behind the lookAt matrix creating exactly the FPS camera you're looking for.

Comment: very nice, looks like the tutorial I was missing. Will give some feedback once I'm through. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it appeared to be that one of my matrices was upside down, causing this problem. 
The tutorial mentioned above was very helpful to find out. So if anyone stumbles across such an issue, it can be a simple math problem and indeed glm::lookAt does all I need.